# remember me functionality symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, remember-me

I am working on symfony 2.4 framework. How to add remember me functionality in login form ???

**security.yml**

```
firewalls:
        admin_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path:  login
                check_path:  login_check
                default_target_path: /user
                #username_parameter: username
                #password_parameter: password
                remember_me: true

            remember_me:
                key: "%secret%"
                lifetime: 31536000
                path: /user
                domain: ~
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing `always_remember_me` in `remember_me`, so do it like that:

```
remember_me:
    key: "%secret%"
    lifetime: 31536000
    path: /user
    domain: ~
    always_remember_me: true
```